# How to change the value of a string stored in a variable with the value from another variable?

Tags: scripting, variable

```
var1="Oct 10 07:34"
var2="35"
```

I want the output as `Oct 10 07:35` (value 35 needs to be from the var2).

Answer (score 3):

Use [`shell (POSIX sh/bash/Korn/zsh) parameter substitution expansion.`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) as following.

```
echo "${var1%:*}:${var2}"
```

- `${var1%:*}` (cut-up-to-first-suffix): This removes everything from end of string until first colon `:` seen, then print a colon `:`, finally print value of variable `var2`

Answer (score 2):

With `bash` or recent versions of `zsh`:

```
$ var1="Oct 10 07:34"
$ var2=35
$ echo "${var1:0:-2}${var2}"
```

Output:

> Oct 10 07:35

With `zsh` or `yash`:

```
$ echo "${var1[1,-3]}$var2"
```